# 2017 4K iMac stuck in Boot Loop

Tags: imac, startup, big-sur

I have a 2017 4K iMac that failed an in-place upgrade from High Sierra to Big Sur.

It is currently in a boot loop, where the Apple logo will appear with a progress bar, the progress bar will proceed to about 1/3 completion, then the mouse will appear, the progress bar will regress to the start, then the machine will gracefully shutdown and reboot (you can see the circular progress icon for a few seconds), starting the process all over again.

My goal is to get the machine wiped with a fresh copy of Monterey installed. The data that's currently on the machine has no importance whatsoever.

I built a macOS Monterey install USB. Plugging it into the machine and holding the option key has no impact on the boot process. The Apple logo still quickly appears and it enters the boot loop. The same thing happens when pressing and holding "T" to try and enter Target Disk Mode.

Holding "D" for diagnostics or "R" for recovery, or any combinations of those keys to try the internet-variants of the tools just causes the machine to sit on a black screen.

I am able to get into single-user mode with Cmd+S, but I'm not sure what good that will do for me. I am also able to boot in verbose mode, but the text disappears whenever this mysterious error happens, and when the text comes back, it is simply informational that the machine is shutting down.

I've tried multiple NVRAM and SMC resets to no avail. Is this machine thoroughly bricked or is there something I'm missing? Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's Cmd/R for Recovery, Cmd/Opt/R for Internet Recovery [though that should be automatic if there's no valid onboard recovery partition]. I'd first try to get back to High Sierra via one of these. I get the feeling you've missed a firmware update by trying to jump so far in one go.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm thinking you're on the right track about the failed firmware update. That is my suspicion as well. Unfortunately Cmd+R and Cmd+Opt+R just leave me at a blank black screen.

Comment: @WalterKlaus if I remember correctly, there was a firmware update between high sierra and mojave, and another one from big sure to Monterey. Maybe you can try reflashing the firmware (but, from experience, this is VERY difficult - the tiny clip, the unreliable readers, getting the firmware, basically everything about it).

Comment: I'd try to go back to High Sierra from USB first. If that works, then update in stages. If not, it might be a trip to an Apple Store. you can get all the old installers here - https://support.apple.com/HT211683